# using eval() function, how to evaluate an expression for a code under observation in python

Tags: python, eval

I am creating a simple debugger using python and trying to create breakpoint when an expression holds.i am using the eval function to evaluate that expression.but it does not work.

```
def traceit(frame, event, trace_arg):
    if event == 'line':
        if(eval('x == 5')):
             print 'stop here'


def fn():
    #the variable x is defined and used here

sys.settrace(traceit)
fn()
sys.settrace(None)
```

Comment: `pdb` wasn't good enough?

Comment: indeed I have to implement it.it is assignment!

Comment: As a side note, You should post the entire traceback if python gives you one, and a much more descriptive explanation of the problem in either case.

Comment: I also think you need to return `traceit` from `traceit` if you want to trace more than 1 line in the function, but that's just my guess from a quick look at the docs on `sys.settrace`...

Answer (score 3):

You need to pass a dictionary as an argument for `locals` and `globals` to the `eval` function (so that it knows what `x` is! -- Otherwise it's just guessing and it picks up the local context which isn't the context of the function `fn`)

You can get the locals and globals values from the stack frame object in the `f_locals` and `f_globals` attributes respectively.

I think you probably want something like:

```
eval('x == 5',frame.f_locals,frame.f_globals)
```

As a side note, you probably don't actually need `eval` for this (static) case:

```
if frame.f_locals.get('x') == 5:
   print "stop here"
```

---

Here's some "working" code (i.e. it prints "stop here" in the right spot):

```
import sys

def traceit(frame, event, trace_arg):
    if event == 'line':
        if 'x' in frame.f_locals or 'x' in frame.f_globals:
            if(eval('x == 5',frame.f_locals,frame.f_globals)):
                print 'stop here'
    return traceit

sentinel = object()
def trace_no_eval(frame, event, trace_arg):
    if event == 'line':
        value = frame.f_locals.get('x',frame.f_globals.get('x',sentinel))
        if value is not sentinel and value == 5:
            print 'stop here'
    return traceit


def fn():
    for x in range(10):
        print x

sys.settrace(traceit)
fn()
sys.settrace(trace_no_eval)
fn()
sys.settrace(None)
```

As you said that this is an assignment, *please do not blindly copy this*.  Take the time to understand it and really understand what is going on.

Comment: thank you very much..it works.
but still when i print the output of the eval function it prints many many other things. Do you have any idea what are these?

Comment: Those other things are being printed from `fn()`.  I don't know what your code is supposed to do other than just `print`.  Actually stopping the execution and interacting etc. is a whole different question entirely.

Comment: my code is supposed to stop execution if an expression - like x == 5- is evaluated to true.
how can i print just the output of the eval function?

Comment: @ajabal -- `print eval(...)` ?  If you want to really stop execution there, then you could just `sys.exit()` after you `print "stop here"`.  I think that should work.  Otherwise, `os._exit()`, but that's not ideal ...

Comment: not to stop everything the user can resume execution.
i mean i have many commands for my debugger e.g to pause execution for a breakpoint or watchpoint.

Comment: @ajabal -- I didn't think that was what you actually wanted.  However, that's beyond the scope of this question and could be the subject of another question entirely.  (I would need a lot more detail about what you actually needed to do before I would attempt to answer that one ...).  But given reasonable constraints, it shouldn't be too hard to take the above code and modify it as you need.  If you have problems with that after trying, then I think it would be reasonable to open a new question (as long as it's clear that it is a different problem than what you had in this question).